# Can i join pagelist and search in one index?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

```
    public ActionResult Index(string search = "")
    {
        var data = GetZamowienia(search);
        ViewBag.search = search;
        ViewBag.Pojazd = new SelectList((from p in db.Pojazd select new
        {
            ID = p.IDPojazdu,
            FullPojazd = p.Marka + " " + p.Model }),
            "ID",
            "FullPojazd",
            null);
        return View(data);
    }

    public ActionResult Index(int? page)
    {
        var zamowienie = db.Zamowienie;
        int maxRows = 1;
        IOrderedQueryable<Zamowienie> zamowienia = (from zam in db.Zamowienie
                                                    select zam)
        .OrderBy(prac => prac.IDPracownika);
        int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
        return View(zamowienia.ToPagedList(pageNumber, maxRows));
    }

    public List<Zamowienie> GetZamowienia(string search)
    {
        {
            var v = (from a in db.Zamowienie
                     where
                             a.Pracownik.Imie.Contains(search)
                     select a
                            );
            return v.ToList();
        }
    }
```

here is error:
The current request for action 'Index' on controller type 'ZamowienieController' is ambiguous between the following action methods:
System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Index(System.String) on type webrent.Controllers.ZamowienieController
System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Index(System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]) on type webrent.Controllers.ZamowienieController

I dont know how to make working pagelist and search together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is telling you that you have two methods with the name Index.

Here are two approaches which you can use to resolve this error.

**Approach one : one Index method with multiple parameters**

```
public ActionResult Index(string search = "", int? page = null)
{
    // Your code here
}
```

In your request URL fill in the parameters which you want to use.

For example:

- myUrl.extension/controller/index?search=abcdef
- myUrl.extension/controller/index?page=3
- myUrl.extension/controller/index?search=abcdef&page=3

**Approach 2 : Routes**

Configure a route on your methods

```
[Route("SearchByName"]
public ActionResult Index(string search = "")
{
   // Your code here
}
```

The URL should look like this now:
myUrl.extension/controller/SearchByName?search=abcdef

```
[Route("GetByPage)]
public ActionResult Index(int? page)
{
    // Your code here
}
```

The url should look like this now:
myUrl.extension/controller/GetByPage?page=3